# How can I inverse a regex expression to use it in java replaceAll method?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall, regex-lookarounds, character-class

I need a last alphabetic character of string example: `ABRACADABRA123456`. The regex expression `[a-zA-Z](?=\d+)` give me the match in all my cases. How can I change (inverse) the expression to use it in java method e.g.: `"ABRACADABRA123456".replaceAll(<inverse-regex>,"")`?

INPUT:`ABRACADABRA123456`
USE:`"ABRACADABRA123456".replaceAll(...)`
OUTPUT:`A` (a last alphabetic character of string)

RESOLVED:`System.out.println("ABRACADABRA123456".replaceAll("([\\D]+)([a-zA-Z](?=\\d+))([\\d]+)","$2")));`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: expected output a alphabetic character in parentheses: `ABRACADABR(A)123456`

Comment: @usmandam If the original regex is ‘a letter before some digits’, then what is the ‘inverse’? A letter *after* some digits? A letter *not* followed by digits? A digit before some letters? I could go on...

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z](?=\d+)` won't match the last alphabetic character.

```
System.out.println("ABRACADABRA123456".replaceAll("([A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z]*$)","($1)"));
```

The above regex would capture the alphabet only if it's followed by any non-alphabetic character zero or more times until the last. So it matches only the last alphabet.

**Output:**

```
ABRACADABR(A)123456
```

Comment: expected output is the last `A`

Comment: see the above regex. It matches the last A. you could use the above regex in pattern and matcher classes also.